# Change image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

i have two ViewControllers, when i tap a cell i need to open other viewController and see image (image with names 1, 2, 3,...._full.jpg), so i write:

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

[dvc updateImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

in my **dvc**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];
    [self.image setTag:1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.image];
}
```

method what i called

```
-(void)updateImage:(NSString*)imageName
{
    [(UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_full.jpg", imageName]]];
}
```

smth like `self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_full.jpg", imageName]];`  didn't work for me.

so, these code works fine in my IOS 5,6,7 emulators, but when i compile it on my IPad 2, IOS 5.1 my image is not updating, all i see is gray background.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This may or may not be the case, but the device is case sensitive but the simulator is not.  Is the string you are trying to load EXACTLY the name of the file on the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg, XCode is joking, it's all because of my images where not ".jpg" they where ".JPG"!. I'm angry...

Answer (score 0):

You run

```
[dvc updateImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
```

After that viewDidLoad is called and your image is reseted.
Instead that pass image name as a string

```
[dvc setImageName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
```

and in DetailViewController.m in viewDidLoad call

```
[self updateImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_full.jpg", self.imageName]];
```

Remember to add @property imageName to your DetailViewController.h file.

Comment: Thank you, but what is setImageName?

Comment: You should add @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *imageName; to your DetailViewController.h file. And setImageName: will set this value. After that update your updateImage: method in DetailViewController.m to use it (self.imageName).

Comment: i'm crying, it works perfectly in my emulator but on IPad i can't see my image

Comment: is your Simulator simulating an iPhone or an iPad?

Comment: Have you got any error? Do you know which line produce the error? Try remove the code which show image and see is it what cause the problem. This code should work fine. I believe there is other issue you have.